# Excel formula extractor

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula

Does anybody know a good python library which can take as an input an Excel formula, and is able to give a canonical translation in programming language of that formula, as well as a list of the cells used in the calculations?

The goal is to translate a large excel file into readable code.